# How to set value of a Parent GridView control from PopUp?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which has a control .say a `LinkButton` when i click on this LinkButton(of parent page's GridView) I am opening a popup which also has a GridView and a column with `LinkButtons` now when i click on this `LinkButton`(of pop up GridView).. the PopUp closes and the name or the text value is passed to parent page.. I have this much working. Not i want to set this value which i have retrieved from PopUp GridView to the Parent Page's GridView `LinkButton` which initially called the PopUp.

**Parent Page**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">click</asp:LinkButton>
                    <br />                    
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function FillTextFromPopup(text) {
        alert(text);       
    }
</script>
```

**Parent Page's Code Behind **

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
            int index = gvRow.RowIndex;
            LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)gvRow.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            string id = lnk.ID;
            Session["myID"] = id;
            string myScript;
            myScript = "<script>window.open('PopUpTest1.aspx?',null,'height=750, width=1024,status= no,resizable= no, scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no'); </script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", myScript, false);
        }
```

**PopUp Page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click1" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**PopUp Page's Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("a", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("b", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("c", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("d", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(1, "Indocin1", "David1", DateTime.Now,"arbaaz");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Enebrel1", "Sam1", DateTime.Now,"Ravish");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "Hydralazine1", "Christoff1", DateTime.Now,"Gulzar");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "Combivent1", "Janet1", DateTime.Now,"Anas");
        table.Rows.Add(5, "Dilantin1", "Melanie1", DateTime.Now,"Danish");

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    protected void LinkButton1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        int index = gvRow.RowIndex;
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)gvRow.FindControl("LinkButton1");        
        string myScript=lnk.Text;
        string aaa = "javascript:window.opener.FillTextFromPopup('"+myScript+"'); window.close();";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), ClientID, aaa, true);   

    }
```

Comment: A Event Programming would work better. The answer is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105602/call-child-control-on-parent-page-for-an-update-of-an-updatepanel/19108332#19108332

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to change some values on the parent page grid.

1. Just access the parent page * DOM Element on java script and change it.
2. another is pass data on to parent page using query string while closing the popup. and onload of parent page you can change whatever you want