# How to set the value of a server control using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Can i set a value of a server control if i pass the ClientID of that server control to the javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FillTextFromPopup(text) {
        alert(text);
        var myID = '<%= Session["myID"].ToString() %>';
        alert(myID);

            document.getElementById(myID).value = 'abc';

    }
</script>


protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
            int index = gvRow.RowIndex;
            LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)gvRow.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            string id = lnk.ClientID;
            Session["myID"] = id;
            string myScript;
            myScript = "<script>window.open('PopUpTest1.aspx?',null,'height=750, width=1024,status= no,resizable= no, scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no'); </script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", myScript, false);

    }
```

Comment: And your error is? Because it should work

Comment: No error.. its just not working, also in visual studio  while typing `document.getElementById(myID).value`  i am unable to find `.value`

Comment: Try to find in html source element with and id equals to myID

Comment: the link button will be anchor tag (which does not have value attribute) use innerHTML or (innerText or textContent)

Comment: none of those are visible in intellisense.

Comment: not all properties/attributes are available on intellense

Comment: @jerjer but its not working either..

Comment: Can you confirm document.getElementById(myID) is not null?

Comment: @jerjer yes i can confirm that myID is not null its getting the correct values such as `ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_LinkButton1_1 `

Comment: @jerjer please take a look at my previous question.. stackoverflow.com/q/19109200/2064292

I have posted all the code necessary.

Comment: I see, so the link is in the opener window not on the popup window that is why it is not working try this: window.opener.document.getElementById(myID).value = 'abc';

Comment: @jerjer nope not working.

Comment: sorry, please change .value to .innerHTML

Comment: not working. You can copy paste the code i have posted in my previous question... and try it out. None of these are working.

Comment: @jerjer innerHTML is working.. but only one row linktext can be changed at a time .. i mean the previous selection is erased in parent GridView.

Comment: it because getElementById returns only 1 element and ID also must be unique, you should use class instead and loop those elements with that class

Comment: No i mean why does it loses previous selections?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the innerText property for LinkButton controls:

Change

```
document.getElementById(myID).value = 'abc';
```

to

```
document.getElementById(myID).textContent = 'abc';
```

Comment: For understanding relationship please read my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/19109200/2064292

I tried what you advised but it is still not working.. although i am getting the correct rendered id of the linkbutton in alert .

Comment: If you look at the HTML source in developer tools can you check if the alerted ID is actually the ID of that control or if it has changed due to the post back? You might need to set ClientIdMode="Static" on the LinkButton

Comment: I already did that and the id is same `ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_LinkButton1_1` both before and after postback. I also tried to change `document.getElementById(myID).value = 'abc';` to `document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_LinkButton1_1').value = 'abc';` it still did not work.

Comment: I've corrected the solution above. You need to use innerText to set the text of the LinkButton

Comment: I have tried that one too my friend and still no luck. :( `innerText` is also not in intellisense

Comment: document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_LinkButton1_1').textContent = 'abc'; document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_LinkButton1_1').innerText= 'abc';

Comment: of you are sure that no html content will be assigned use the inner HTML document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_LinkButton1_1').innerHTML = 'abc';

Comment: This works for me:  <div><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkButton1">Test</asp:LinkButton>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var el = document.getElementById('<%=lnkButton1.ClientID%>');
        el.innerText = "NewText";
</script>

Comment: innerText is not w3c compliant attribute, it worked on some browser though but for maximum compatibility is to use the 2 innerText and textContent

Comment: @guymid my linkbutton is in GridView